# Maximum size of Parameter Object in Query?

Tags: neo4j, graphaware, neo4j-php-ogm

I am using the [graphaware php client for neo4j](https://github.com/graphaware/neo4j-php-client).

When running a query with a "large" parameter object (about 200 lines in pretty print, field values are 30 characters max), it freezes.

The `$queryparams` object looks like

```
{
    "data": {
        "someproperty": 30000,
        "anotherproperty": "stringentry",
        <about 200 more like this here, partially nested>
    }
}
```

where

1. everything is inside the data wrapper
2. most of the 200 entries are garbage that the query never uses

The line

```
$queryresult = $client->run($query, $queryparams);
```

becomes long-running and gets time-outed by nginx. I tried

```
try
{
    $queryresult = $client->run($query, $queryparams);
} catch (Neo4jException $e)
{
    return "error";
}
```

to no avail.

Running the same query with the same parameters in the neo4j browser, I get my results instantaneously.

Any ideas about what is causing the problem? Is it graphaware?

**EDIT:** I posted too fast, but this was unexpected to me: there is a field `"0": ...` somewhere in the `$queryparams` inside the garbage I mentioned. That is what causing the problem. Is this intended behaviour?

Comment: Yes, map keys can only be alphabetical

Comment: @ChristopheWillemsen, that does not seem to be the whole story: alphanumeric is allowed (even starting with numbers) as long as the key is not consisting entirely of numbers. Also, when using http instead of bolt, i can even use number-only keys. Still - is it really intended that the php class freezes (instead of throwing an exception)?

Comment: yes bolt should throw an exception as well, would you be able to provide the query and a dump of the parameters passed so I can create a test for it