# Neo4j graphaware php $client->run($query) is long-running

Tags: php, neo4j, graphaware

I am using [neo4j graphaware php client](https://github.com/graphaware/neo4j-php-client) and having bad issues with long-running queries.

```
$client->run($query, $params);
```

is long running and ultimately causing a `504 Gateway Time-out`.

I recently opened a question concerning the [issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45565713/maximum-size-of-parameter-object-in-query) and I thought I identified the cause, namely parameters named only `"0"`. I was lucky to find out the cause back then.

I am having the same issue again and not being lucky identifying the cause. I am not able to reliably reproduce it. I thought I could just impose a timeout on queries in the neo4j config, so that the graphaware client gets interrupted and I can handle the error / log the data. But that doesn't work, it seems I never even get to invoke the query in neo4j.

It seems I need something like the timeout:

```
$client = ClientBuilder::create()
    ->setDefaultTimeout(3)
    ->build();
```

which, unfortunately is deprecated/doesn't work.

**TL;DR:** Something blocks graphaware client and I see no way of finding out what it is. Ideas?

Comment: With http, you can set the timeout longer as explained in the README. Not for Bolt yet. Secondly it would be good to know what your query is and a dump of the given parameters.